# Re-use the same terraform backend between multiple applications?

Tags: continuous-integration, terraform, continuous-deployment

So suppose I use terraform to build infrastructure for and deploy several unrelated applications, will I need to create a dedicated backend (PostgreSQL database in my case) for each one or can I re-use the same one? Technically I should be able to do that - why shouldn't I? Simply having more than one record in the corresponding table. But I've never seen it mentioned anywhere either in docs or in the community. So I'm not sure.

Can someone either confirm or refute this?

Comment: Why do you think Terraform would make this an issue? Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: 'cause it's not mentioned anywhere. Do you know if it can? I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Why would it be mentioned if it can just do it? It would be an odd limitation but a lot of this is going to come down to how you structure your code which is largely down to what requirements you have. A lot of people will specifically want to not used a shared database and so will structure their Terraform code to deploy a new database for each service. But they might, for example, share the same VPC so there's common patterns for that. It's hard to tell what could be an issue here unless you actually run into a problem and then edit your question to show what problem you have.

Comment: 'cause other backends might not be able to do it.

You didn't answer the question. Do you know that it can or just theorizing here (like me)?

Comment: Your question is too vague as it is because you don't have an actual problem stated in the question. If you used the postgresql provider you can easily create more tables in the same database instance and they'd be completely unaware of them if the state for each was in different state files. If you try to do this and run into an issue then your question should state exactly what problem you're hitting.

Comment: My question isn't vague. It's a very definitive - yes or no question. Vague are your speculative responses.

Comment: The answer is yes you can do it unless you can provide an example showing that you can't for some weird usage.